# Hide div if another Div is empty

Tags: jquery

Im trying to hide a div if another div is empty, but for some reason it wont work as I want.

so basically I want to hide the `<div class="more_post">` if the `<div class="last_post">` element is empty

```
<div id="toggle-view">
        <div class="more_post">
            <h5>Load more</h5>
        </div>
        <ul class="toggle-view">
            <div class="toggle"">                     
                <div class="last_post"> </div>
            </div> 
        </ul>   
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
if($("#toggle-view ul.toggle-view .toggle .last_post").length ==0)
    {
    $("#toggle-view .more_post").hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.html()` to read the HTML from the DIV first.

```
if($("#toggle-view ul.toggle-view .toggle .last_post").html().length ==0)
    {
    $("#toggle-view .more_post").hide();
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gMC6F/

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm in the fiddle, but nothing is happening on my page site:(

Comment: @Dymond Hmm, weird. Either `.html()` or `.text()` should read the DIV's content and should be able to be done a `.length` in it.

Comment: Iknow, It was working fine until this morning. Cant figure it out whats the problem now.:/

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:-

```
if $('#toggle-view ul.toggle-view .toggle .last_post').is(':empty') $(this).hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if($("#toggle-view ul.toggle-view .toggle .last_post").html().length ==0)
{
$("#toggle-view .more_post").hide();
}
```

[**Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/C26u7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#toggle-view .more_post").toggle($("#toggle-view ul.toggle-view .toggle .last_post").html().length > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. It will work Simple method.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if(!$.trim( $(".last_post").html() ) == true)
$(".more_post").hide();

});
</script>
```

**[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/C26u7/1/)**

Thank you